# How to set user permission for a particular user?

Tags: permissions, civicrm-home

I have two accounts. One is admin and another is observer.
I want only read-only permission for demo account.
Please help.
If I logged in by observer account then that CiviCRM option not showing on dashboard.

[image: Logged in by Admin]

[image: Logged in by observer]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dipak,

You will need to add permission for roles to access certain CiviCRM functionality. You can do this by navigating to CiviCRM >> Administer >> Users and permisions >>Permissions (Access Control). And then click on Drupal Access Control. Give permission to specific role and save the form.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: when I logged in by observer -> "access denied " message came.

Comment: I want to access dashlet of civicrm then which kind of permission should I give?

Comment: You need to clear what you tried. You will need to added permissions using Admin role and then try with observer

Comment: I want civiCRM tab on that navigation bar.

Comment: Did you try playing around with permissions? You may need to give Access CiviCRM permission to have that link visible for user.

Comment: I am not getting sir. I just create a account and assign some permission like view contact

Comment: So if you need link on navigation menu and to access /civicrm page then user will need 'Access CiviCRM' permission else you directly hit the URL to view contact or dashboard.